# Firestore Date loses timezone offset after retrieval and saving back to database

Tags: javascript, date, nativescript, google-cloud-firestore, timezone-offset

My local time zone is UTC+2.

I am building a NativeScript app that has a [RadCalendar](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radcalendar.html) control, in which the user can select dates.  In my scenario the user selects 29, 30 and 31 January 2018.

A `console.dir()` output of the selected dates shows as follows:

```
=== dump(): dumping members ===
JS: [
JS:     "2018-01-28T22:00:00.000Z",
JS:     "2018-01-29T22:00:00.000Z",
JS:     "2018-01-30T22:00:00.000Z"
JS: ]
JS: === dump(): dumping function and properties names ===
```

Clearly the RadCalendar is converting the values to UTC, which is cool.  I then save those dates to my Firestore database, where they are stored in my local time, and with the timezone info preserved, as shown in this screenshot of my FireStore console:
[image]

So far so good.
Now the problem seems to come about when I read those records from the FireStore database back into my app (and into the RadCalendar control's `.selectedDates` property).

After readback, a `console.log()` of the retrieved document snapshot shows as follows:

```
{
"theDate":"Jan 31, 2018 12:00:00 AM",
"available":false,
"memberUid":"N76BviTCX8fLdErAjMHYqx2GEU63",
"organizationUid":"zv5A7UC8B7bKzePGPyaJ"
}
```

Notice that the timezone info is gone.  I imagine that at this point the executing code is still "local-timezone-aware", and the date (for my local timezone) is not incorrect.  But the problem comes in when changing the 'available' property and saving the record back to FireStore.

See what the date value in FireStore console looks like now:
[image]

Notice that it is not a date in FireStore anymore, but a string.

The Chrome DevTools debugger for NativeScript actually revealed that at the point of retrieving the data back into the app, the retrieved date property is already a string and not a Date anymore.  Might be worth mentioning that I'm using [this NativeScript-Firebase plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/FIRESTORE.md) to do the interactions with Firestore...could it be that the root problem is in that plugin library?

How can I ensure that the values I get back out of the FireStore database are preserved as dates in my code?

Comment: it looks like you get a timestamp, not a utc stamp or whatever the correct name is, it might be to do with how they store the tme?

Comment: Don't post images, post text. Not everyone can see images.

Comment: @RobG what text do you recommend I replace the "screenshots" of the Firebase console with?!?  Their purpose is specifically to show how the Firestore console is interpreting the stored values.

Comment: You could show the string displayed in the image.

Comment: @ShawndeWet Did you found any solution?

Comment: @Subhan the problem was resolved by an update to the NativeScript-Firebase plugin if I recall correctly.